# How can I list and sell Stellar based Tokens (not XLM)?

Tags: xlm, token, exchanges, issuing

Reading this example (https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/), I can see that creating a token on Stellar is straight forward. I'm not completely sure how to do it yet, but I do understand the overall concepts.

That being said, once a token is created, what are the ways to trade/exchange Stellar tokens? Are there existing platforms, like the Stellar equivalent of EtherDelta? Or is this something that needs to be handled one by one?

For clarification, I am talking about XLM based tokens, as opposed to XLM itself. XLM tokens, from what I understand, are tokens with a defined supply and condition.

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Most [wallets](https://www.stellar.org/lumens/wallets/) support all functions needed for the token creation and distribution.

The process is really straightforward.

1. Create two account keypairs: the **issuing** and **holder** accounts.
2. Fund both accounts, send 1.5 XLM to issuing account and 3 XLM to the holder account.
3. Login to the **holder** account from any wallet and create a **trustline** to your **issuing** account. Asset code: `COOLTOKEN`, issuer account: `PUBLIC_KEY_OF_THE_ISSUER_ACCOUNT`.
4. Issue some tokens. Use [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) or wallet that supports asset creation. In order to issue a token you just need to send tokens from the **issuer** to the **holder** account. So transfer 1000 `COOLTOKEN`s to the account `PUBLIC_KEY_OF_THE_HOLDER_ACCOUNT`. That's it, you have issued 1000 `COOLTOKEN`s.
5. Now you are ready to distribute your token. Login to the **holder** wallet and make an offer on the Stellar Decentralized Exchange through the wallet interface (most wallets support this function). Let's sell 100 `COOLTOKEN`s for 1000 XLM each. From that moment anyone who owns a Stellar account can purchase your token.

All mentioned operations can be executed using the [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) interface, or directly from the code, using the SDK for you preferred language.

If you wish to sell your tokens for other coins, you should contact exchanges in order to get your token listed. [Bifrost](https://bifrost.stellar.org/) is another option which allows you to sell your token for ETH.

In order to confirm the account ownership, make sure to set up `home_domain` for your accounts and [provide metadata](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/1380/366) for your new asset in `stellar.toml`. You can also list your issuer and distribution accounts on [StellarExpert Directory](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/1803/366).

Comment: Thanks. This is very clear. You also answered my other question which was about whether or not tokens need to map one-to-one.

Comment: Cool :) Consider deleting the second question if it was fully covered here.