# How a new created token to be listed on Stellarterm directory?

Tags: token

We had done and followed the instructions from https://github.com/stellarterm/stellarterm/tree/master/directory/ to create tokens on StellarTerm. We are able to search the new created token. However, it's not listed in the directory. I'd appreciate that if anybody can help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps taken from stellarterm github, you need to follow these steps

https://github.com/stellarterm/stellarterm/tree/master/directory#first-show-that-you-have-9-things-needed

```
Fork the repo to your own account
Add an anchor+asset in the directory.js
Add a trading pair in the correct section
While inside the directory folder, run ./checkBuild.sh
Check in all the files. Commit with meaningful message
Push to GitHub and create a PR.
In your pull request, please show that all the requirements have been met.
```

Once approved, your token will start to show on stellarterm.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more information about how to get listed on StellarTerm from their Github

https://github.com/stellarterm/stellarterm/tree/master/directory

Comment: Thanks All, We are in a test mode in local to try out the procedures in the pull request document except step 5-6, which require to push Git and create a PR. Is this the reason I can't see my token listed on directory?

Answer (score 0):

Stellerterm team have to approve your pull request

Comment: Could you please expand upon this.  It would make a much better answer with some references or pointer how to obtain approval.

Comment: The second step is requesting a pull request https://github.com/stellarterm/stellarterm/tree/master/directory#second-create-a-pull-request

You have to put all info in that request like reddit link, stellar.toml url ..

Answer (score 0):

Publish token on the stellar network.

https://www.stellar.org/blog/tokens-on-stellar/

Hope useful for you

Answer (score 0):

[StellarExpert](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/directory) maintains the largest and most up-to-date list of all well-known Stellar addresses. The Directory is is available using [open API](https://github.com/orbitlens/stellar-expert-explorer/blob/master/docs/api/directory.md) and is completely free. To list new address in StellarExpert Directory, send an email to orbit.lens@gmail.com containing the following information:

- Stellar account address you want to add (`GA7K...6NLE`)
- Organization domain name (`example.com`)
- Organization title (`MySuperOrg`, `NewCoolExchange` etc)
- Account type (`exchange`, `anchor`, `issuer`, `distributor`)

In order to simplify the verification process and confirm the ownership, make sure that the account `home_domain` is set and the appropriate `stellar.toml` is [hosted](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/1380/366) on this domain. If the address belongs to the anchor operational account, please provide the required `memo` type and supported top-up operations (`payment`, `path_payment`, `merge_account`).