# Asset not verified

Tags: assets, verification, stellar.toml

StellarExpert says that related domain for my [asset](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/CCC-GDEH2IUXOBIJXMX5KTQSKYB4E2DGQCT34LCJM3TG7JQFJO6FTONQHTUC) was not found.

I published `toml` file as `https://capitalcryptoworld.io/.well-known/stellar.toml`, where `capitalcryptoworld.io` is my domain name.

Why my asset is not verified?

Answer (score 5):

Here is a step-by-step process of the basic asset verification:

1. Set [`home_domain`](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/accounts.html#home-domain) field for your asset issuing account. Clients can look up a `stellar.toml` from this domain.

   - This should be in the format of a [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) such as `example.com`, `anchor.example.com` etc.
   - DO NOT include scheme (i.e. `http` or `https`) and trailing relative path: `https://example.com` or `example.com/tokens` won't work.
   - Find more details and code samples [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html#discoverablity-and-meta-information).
2. Create `stellar.toml` following directions from the official Stellar [guide](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html).

   - Do not forget to add the `[[CURRENCIES]]` for each of your assets.
   - Provide a short meaningful asset description (parameters `name`,
     `desc` and `conditions`) to tell your users what it's all about
     (optional).
3. Publish your `stellar.toml` file, clients will search it at the following location: `https://your_domain.com/.well-known/stellar.toml`.

   - Make sure that CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) is [enabled](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html#enabling-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors).
   - Also check the content type, should be `content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.  Some clients/browsers may not handle it correctly if content is transferred as `application/octet-stream`, not `text/plain` as expected.

Comment: [[CURRENCIES]]
code="CCC"
issuer="GDEH2IUXOBIJXMX5KTQSKYB4E2DGQCT34LCJM3TG7JQFJO6FTONQHTUC"
display_decimals=4
name="CCC"
desc="1 CCC token represent 1 cat in the world"
conditions="There will only ever be 1,000,000,000 CCC tokens in existence."
image="https://capitalcryptoworld.io/images/logo.png"
this is my toml file tell me which thing should i include in it

Comment: Field `home_domain` is not set for the issuing account [`GDEH2IUXOBIJXMX5KTQSKYB4E2DGQCT34LCJM3TG7JQFJO6FTONQHTUC`](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/account/GDEH2IUXOBIJXMX5KTQSKYB4E2DGQCT34LCJM3TG7JQFJO6FTONQHTUC).

Comment: how i set the home domain?

Comment: See paragraph 1. "Find more details and code samples [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/issuing-assets.html#discoverablity-and-meta-information)."

Comment: i follow the step but it not verified the asset

Comment: how to set the federation server FEDERATION_SERVER="https://capitalcryptoworld.io/federation" line include every toml file which i saw

Comment: how to set the federation server FEDERATION_SERVER="https://capitalcryptoworld.io/federation" line include every toml file which i saw

Answer (score 3):

OrbitLens does a good walkthrough of the steps needed.

Ultimately, your asset isn't set as verified because you haven't added a homedomain to the issuing account.

A stellar.toml isn't any good if the network doesn't know how to find it.

Comment: i follow this article https://medium.com/@katopz/how-to-set-home-domain-and-get-verified-on-stellar-1ae9986e37f1 to set the home domain but my asset is not verified

Answer (score 0):

You also have to enable CORS. Don't forget that step it took me days to figure it out. Even though the guidelines says to do it, it's easily overlooked and if you're not familiar, very confusing.

https://stellarport.io/assets/alphanum4/VOID/GB4UBYTLHNDDIP75CZRWE2LTM3M7UCWHVPEM4FPUXGUWMJFSWTGBEZDO

https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/VOID-GB4UBYTLHNDDIP75CZRWE2LTM3M7UCWHVPEM4FPUXGUWMJFSWTGBEZDO

Here is the asset I created please feel free to ask me any questions if you have them.

Comment: That is step 3 of OrbitLens' answer.